# Npm mysql - can't I query WHERE conditions using a single object?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, npm, where-clause

I am using express and npm mysql ([Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql))

I want to do a call using

```
query('SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ?', where, cb)
```

where is a javascript object f.e. : {col1: 'one', col2: 'two'}

But it seems that this doesn't work. It works for SET though to update multiple columns at once.

I want a general method where I can send a different combination of columns to search. I was wondering if there is a built in method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I created this script:

```
var andQuery = "";
  var andParams = [];
  var isFirst = true;

  for (var filter in where) {
    if (where.hasOwnProperty(filter)) {

        if(!isFirst) {
           andQuery += " AND ? ";
        } else {
           andQuery += " ? ";
           isFirst = false;
        }

      andParams.push({[filter]: where[filter]});  
    }
  }


  db.query(
    'SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE ' + andQuery, andParams, (err, results) => {
```